# alt+tab application switcher like in windows 7

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

I am new for Linux and Ubuntu. I didn't like unity's built in application switcher.

I have been looking for simple and fast (like in windows 7) application switcher for Ubuntu with unity desktop. Which shows a grid with opened applications and one can switch by using up/down/left/right arrows or by subsequent pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

I have tried all options in compiz and the most close option was static application switcher but I cannot use arrows to switch between windows.

Do you have any suggestion which complies to my needs?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't remember what Windows 7 looks like, but we have different switchers by default in Ubuntu, like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. So far this is the closest one to what I was looking for. Strange that I didn't find this shortcut when googled

Comment: Still this is poor version of windows 7/10 task switcher. You only see  apps which are not minimalised (which is not related if the application is actually running or not) and what you see is small version of window screen without title or icon - well this is matter of taste as I am used to recognize apps by their icon (which is for sure weak when there are more windows of the same app opened at the same time).

Comment: We have the alt+tab switcher which displays apps by icon and then shows you all open windows from this application. Or you can use the same view as super+w, except only displaying windows of the currently focused app. There are many ways to navigate windows. You can even search by typing.

Answer (score 7):

- Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`.Run the below commands to install ccsm,

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
  ```
- Open ccsm--->Window management--->Enable `Shift switcher` plugin.

[image]

- After enabling shift switcher press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.
- Now you can press `arrow keys` to `swap` between windows.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can see all unity shorcuts if you keep Super(windows/command key) pressed.

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to show all windows opened.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hello matsoor welcome to Ask Ubuntu.
I recommend you install Ubuntu Tweak. These instructions enable you to put your mouse in the corner of choice and have it show the windows switcher as if you had pressed <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

In Ubuntu Tweak open up Tweaks then Workspace. Click on one of the four rectangles depending on which corner you want to move your mouse to have all of your windows shown. Click on the rectangle and change the value to Show Windows. I recommend setting it to the top right corner as that seems to be the least visited corner on the screen.
[image: http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6a8f/0w2c9bl7i566cjs6g.jpg]